# Imagens na criação de tema wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou criando um tema wordpress de vans para mudanças, enfim, criei uma página page-vans.php e nela estou mostrando cada categoria de van tendo pequena, media, grande e extragrande, anexei como thumbnail uma imagem e essa imagem é mostrada no index da página para quando clicada nela levar para a página da van selecionada (page-vans.php), o problema é, como posso adicionar outra imagem sem ser a thumbnail?

Para ser exibida na pagina single da van?

Pensei em adicionar pelo conteúdo da página mas ai ela entraria em the_content() só que teria como filtrar somente a imagem do the_content()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver isso você poderia usar custom fields. Usando essa abordagem, você pode inserir mais uma imagem em cada post e chamá-la no seu tema normalmente.

Existem várias formas de fazer isso, desde uma totalmente [manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) como também outras com uso de plugin. Eu particularmente, uso o [Advanced Custom Fields](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). Com ele eu crio um conjunto de campos e atribuo a um `custom post type` ou uma página, por exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma quando eu for criar um novo ou editar um `post` do tipo que foi configurado no `custom field` o campo irá aparecer para inserção do conteúdo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no tema eu faço a chamada do conteúdo do campo:

```
<?php 
    $imageURL = get_field('imagem');
    echo $imageURL;
    // ou simplesmente
    the_field('imagem');
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo

Comment: Feliz por ter ajudado :)